# Glassfish Security: Role changes should take effect immediately

Tags: java, security, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm using a JDBC realm for authentication and authorization. When I remove a role from a user in the DB, the changes are not reflected immediately in the application, only at the next user login. Is it possible that role changes take effect immediately? I know I have to put this logic in the application itself, but I don't know how to apply this changes to a specific user while he's logged in. I'm using GF 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no API-provided ways for this. Your best bet is to wrap the logged-in user (the `UserPrincipal`) in your own `User` model object (can be as good a (JPA) entity of the very same table) which allows changing the role and then collect all logged-in users in some static/application-wide set/map with help of a `Filter` and `HttpSessionListener`. Finally, in the admin panel, just check if the `User` is there in the set/map then get and alter it accordingly. It'll be reflected immediately for the actual enduser.

#### Related questions

- [How to listen on realm events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724074/listen-to-tomcat-realm-authentication-events)
- [How to check which users are all logged-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592961/how-can-i-check-which-all-users-are-logged-into-my-application/4593718#4593718)

Comment: Thanks. How do I alter the UserPrincipal so that it reflects the role changes? The `Principal` class only defines a `getName()` method. Where is the part where I can set the new roles?

Comment: You can't alter it. That's exactly why I proposed to wrap it in your own model object. You just alter the wrapped model object and use it instead throughout your webapp. If you really don't want to change it, then your best bet is to collect sessions of logged-in users and invalidate it. That's only less friendly UX for the enduser. For some hints about how to collect sessions, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372311/jsf-how-to-invalidate-an-user-session-when-he-logs-twice-with-the-same-credentia/2372990#2372990).

Comment: OK, you're saying I should use the wrapped user model, which contains the user roles, and perform role checks against the wrapped model. Problem is, I'm also using the Java EE security annotations auch as @RolesAllowed("Rolename") in my EJBs and the p:ifGranted tag from PrimeFaces. Those checks would still use the possibly out-dated roles. So I guess I need to invalidate the sessions...

Comment: Ah yes, didn't forsee those issues. Right, your best bet is to collect the sessions by user and invalidate them whenever necessary.