# Refresh Glassfish realm to update user roles

Tags: glassfish, roles

I use the security annotations in GlassFish (@RolesAllowed, ...) in combination with a custom realm (based on AppservRealm). When the user logs in the realm returns the assigned user roles via getGroupNames(). Now we've a situation that the roles of the currently logged in user changes (e.g. the user does not longer has the role ADMIN).
Is there a way to trigger a reload of the realm data by GlassFish so e.g. the getGroupNames() will be called by GlassFish an returned the new roles of the currently logged in user?

Comment: According to this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774361/glassfish-security-role-changes-should-take-effect-immediately) there is no way to do that :( Really?